# How to style an panel with image/text?

Tags: openlayers

I'm searching for an example to add a css styled panel with OpenLayers to an OSM-Map. First - is this possible? All examples show how to add controls to an openlayers.control.panel. I just want to add an static infowindow with some html in it.

Best regards ...